# Adding a graph to a SourceQueue so we can run a endless stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am new to the Akka Streams library and decided to learn it with an example.
I am trying to catch all keyboard events and pass it through an endless stream. My idea is i will divide the stream in two do some separate processing and then end them in different sinks.

This is a short example of the event handler i already have that works.

```
object KeyListener extends org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Key-Events-Streaming-System")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val bufferSize = 100
  //if the buffer fills up then this strategy drops the oldest elements
  //upon the arrival of a new element.
  val overflowStrategy = akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropHead
  val queueNativeKeyEvents = Source.queue[NativeKeyEvent](bufferSize, overflowStrategy)
                                                                            .filter(event => event.getRawCode > 0)
                                                                            .to(Sink.foreach(println(_)))
                                                                            .run()
  def nativeKeyPressed(event: NativeKeyEvent): Unit = {
   queueNativeKeyEvents.offer(event)

  }
  def nativeKeyTyped(event: NativeKeyEvent): Unit = {
    System.out.print("test")
  }
  def nativeKeyReleased(event: NativeKeyEvent): Unit = {
    System.out.print("test")
  }
}
```

Now from what i understand i would want a setup where for each key i press a event gets added to the source and travels through the stream i have setup.

How do i configure that kind of a source.
Also when do i "run" the graph i have created ?

I think i am going wrong somewhere with my fundamental understanding of streams.

### Appreciate the help !

**Update** :
Yes the above example works just fine and the stream is run everytime a new element enters it.
The challenge i am dealing with now is i want to divide the filtered stream into a graph if you will that takes one input and divides it to three streams and processes them in different paths down the line.
I think i can create a graph that takes one input , split them in different paths and result in different sinks that eventually do the side effecting work required of each path.
What i cannot wrap my head around is how do i add this graph to the Source Queue ?

Comment: it's not clear what is wrong/missing with the code you already have. could you please clarify?

Comment: Yeah so this is a piece that i got off another StackOverflow question. But i am not sure if this suits my requirement.

Comment: Why do you claim "I think I am going wrong somewhere"?  Is the code not compiling or running as expected?

Comment: what i am wondering is is this the correct way of doing it ?   I am skeptical if this is the correct way of approaching the problem.  The code is compiling and running correctly.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil   Yes you were correct. I was not just confident. I have updated the question with some more information. Please take a look.